# Can a spell be balanced by giving it to the other side?

Tags: balancing-magic-systems

So I have this world mechanic, where after someone kills 5 people, they gain a one time use spell where they can kill all of the remaining enemies, regardless of where they are, what powers they have, or what they are doing. However, this will upset the balance of power in the story. The question is whether or not giving this spell to both sides will make the fight fair. If both sides have the same powers, abilities, and spells, will it make a battle between them fair?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What can I do to fix the question?

Comment: Seems to me like the answer depends greatly on specifics. Who decides what "enemies" means? If it's the caster, could a sufficiently evil person use it as an instant mass-genocide spell? If it's the spell itself, like some sort of sentient magic, how does it make its determination?

Comment: Balance and fairness are subjective qualities that you as a worldbuilder can choose to assess however you wish. Without a specific definition of balance we cannot answer this question for you. Even if you do define your terms, you're effectively asking us to tell you how a fight in your world will play out. This is entirely dependent upon the specific context of a particular fight, especially characters that are participating in the fight. We're not here to tell you how a fight in your world will play out. I don't think you can turn this into a question suitable for this site.

Comment: Is this a game mechanic? Anyhow  As it is written, 'kill all remaining enemies' ;is rather broad. Why wouldn't it include everybody on the other side? So in other words is this not five kills wins the round? game? battle? war?

Comment: This is a game mechanic. When I say enemies, I just mean everyone has the ability. So if person a has a fight with person b, they both have said ability. Also, enemy is defined by "who you want to kill". Enemy is just the target. And I am not asking for who wins, I am asking about rational probabilities and equivalence in capability.

Comment: It would kill everyone on the other side.

Comment: I'm not so assertive as Sphennings on the doability of the question (balance is not purely subjective), however we lack quite some details about how this spells work : exact targets, range, speed and cast time, trigger conditions, etc.. Same about the world : Who owns this spell, and who do they use it against? How many casualties are there in an usual battle? All these kinds of things are important to know before one can understand how far it can be useful to win a fight.

Comment: And balance is objective, since it is obvious that Mike Tyson would beat a 100 year old handicapped person in a fight.

Comment: "Little did I know that my beloved teammate, who I would have totally switched sides to be with, was actually a double agent, so when I cast the spell she also..."

Comment: I said that it kills the enemies regardless of where they are, so distance (and therefore range and speed) don't factor in. Also, they use it against whoever they are fighting. And it works regardless of the target. But I want to make it balanced, and I thought to mitigate its effects on asymmetrical warfighting capability, I could give it to both sides.

Comment: I suppose this might guarantee that "sides" are rarely more than 5 people.  "Don't join up with that group - someone might kill five of them, and then you'd die, too."

Comment: I was wondering if a normally insanely overpowered ability like this could be balanced by both the person using it and the person they are using it on have the ability.

Comment: There are plenty of people throughout history who would be willing to die for a cause. And there is still an advantage to having more people on your team (namely, a higher odds that one of them will get off a spell first).

Comment: And it is not the end, as enemies revive up to 3 times.

Comment: @ScruffyTrooper2181 Then first clearly define the terms : What is an enemy? Someone who might hurt you, someone you think *is* an enemy to you? Then, and that's a game designer advise : don't use absolutes for one individual's actions ; Infinite range and possible targets will almost always lead to one-sided situations unless the spell effects have no meaningful impact. To be balanced, spell effects need to be inversely proportional to the area it effects.

Comment: If my country is at war with your country and I kill five of your soldiers, can I use this spell to delete everyone in your country at once?

Comment: @Daron partially. However, this only applies to soldiers and military assets.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

I think you are basically asking a game theory question. Can you make a game fair simply by giving both sides the same abilities, as a general thing. To which I would say: no.

Abilities, especially overpowered ones, can wreck any game system even if all participants have them. In that case it often comes down to who gets there first -- meeting the requirements for the overpowered ability.

Maybe as one example, good old Wargames (the movie, but also, in general, nuclear war). Is nuclear war fair? "The only winning move is not to play." I think by practical meaning of the word "fair" (which I would define as "all parties have a reasonable chance of winning") nuclear war is never fair and, as the computer in the movie concluded, it always just ends up in disaster for all sides regardless of how it starts or how it progresses.

So no, you cannot balance a power by giving it to all sides.

[Edit: Although there could be a case to be made that such an ability is actually not meant to be balanced. It's "the end game". You reach that condition and basically you win. In that case, though, I would suggest that the lead up has to be way more complex than "5 kills". I'm thinking specifically of games like Supreme Commander, where there are absolutely unbalanced things in the game, but the real game is the lead up to those "insta-win" / "planet killer" things. Once you have one, you probably win. The hard part -- which makes the game fair overall -- is getting there and preventing your opponent from getting there first. So, for the OP, you don't just need "5 kills". You need 5 kills under a full moon on top of a particular ancient pyramid using an obsidian knife made during a new moon and etc etc etc. The ability is a game ender but getting there is tricky.]

Comment: Nuclear war is arguably (a bit) more complex: the only way to guarantee that your enemy does not win by waging nuclear war is to also be capable of waging it.  If only Russia had nukes (for example), they arguably COULD "win" by crippling any geopolitical foes with tactical strikes.  But your general point stands.

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze our choices:

**1. Side A has the spell, side B doesn't know they have it.**

Side A has an overwhelming advantage. Unless side B has a stroke of good luck and kills the mage before the mage can take five heads, side B will always loose.

**2. Side A has the spell, side B knows it.**

Now it's a race between Side A's mage killing five people and side B killing the mage. Note that as explained, if side A's mage feels threatened, he/she can always off of a few of side A's combatants to quickly gain access to the spell.

*I just made an assumption about how the spell operates.*

**3. Side A and side B have the spell.**

Now it's a race to see which mage can kill five people fastest. Only an idiot wouldn't kill the five soldiers standing in front of you, your side or not, or bring along five slaves to off immediately.

**Your spell needs some limits. Right now I judge it to be too powerful and not well enough focused.**

I get that you have game dynamics. You might not even allow the player to attack his/her own team. Still...

- First, the spell should only apply to death dealt to the enemy. Not death dealt to friendly and unsuspecting players.
- Second, the spell should be inoperable if the characters dying aren't actively engaged in the attack. This avoids Side A bringing five hooded prisoners along to quickly off to gain access to the spell.
- Third, The spell should have an actual limit to the number of corpses it can create. Killing every person on the opposing side no matter how large is a *tremendous* advantage to whichever side can use the spell first. In fact, knowing the spell cold be in play might lead generals to reduce attack groups to a bare minimum just to avoid losses.

Comment: Good analysis of the spell's meta's strategy. Dominant actions lead to goals solely based around it. It makes all other choices meaningless, like... If you have to choose between a machine gun and a wooden spoon in a fight : You'll always choose the machine gun.

Comment: What do you mean by limits? I thought I had limits (namely, one time use and needing 5 kills by 1 person). I like your idea about making sure that the players don't kill their teammates. That can be easily managed by not coding a friendly fire mechanic.

Comment: @ScruffyTrooper2181 Killing everybody on the other side is a problem if the other side has a significant number of combatants. You don't explain that. If this is a game that, for example, limits the number of combatants to ten or twenty, then the limit might be a non-issue. But if the game has (e.g.) no limit on combatants, then the threat of this spell is catastrophic to strategic planning. It's godlike in its ability. Thus, limiting the total amount of damage or number of people it can kill should be considered.

Comment: @JBH the game doesn't limit the number of players, but I thought the spell would act as a balancing agent if both sides had it. I often in FPS games that I've tested noticed how when teammate leave the server, you get destroyed because the system can't add new players to your server intentionally because it would take too much resources to do for all servers. So I thought adding this mechanic for team modes only would limit the effects of 30 people vs 5 people. And rewards based on team victory.

Comment: @JBH I still don't know why this is overpowered. My main concern was avoiding making overpowered gameplay elements. I just gave this specific example because I needed to give some kind of reference. I would like to know what makes certain gameplay elements overpowered, and how to avoid the thing that makes them overpowered.

Comment: @ScruffyTrooper2181 If we look from a very gaming point of view, give 100 health points to everyone; Now give them each a weapon which deals 50dmg/s, or 50 DPS. To kill one you need 2s of constant hitting (quite standard in Team based FPS like Paladins or Overwatch). Alright, now trigger the spell : Each target means you do 100hp instantly. 10 targets? You've hit for 1000hp, or 20s of firing. 30 targets? **One full minute** of attacking, this is insane. I'm not even accounting you do the damage safely (you don't need line of sight) and that it's burst damage, preventing any retaliation.

Comment: @Tortliena what if I make respawn happen in 1 second, and make normal damage equal to full health? Then it's just a fast paced game.

Comment: @ScruffyTrooper2181 This site is not really good for long discussions in comments (and I don't want to annoy JBH with all those notifications x)); I just wanted to clarify a bit the thoughts. Once you'll get [the privilege to talk in chat](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) (20 rep), I'll open a chatroom so we can talk about it more if you wish :).

Comment: @Tortliena's explanation is fantastic, but from a player-waiting-for-more-players point of view, the usual solution is that people on the understaffed team just drop out and find another server to play on. Note that dealing with new incoming players is going to be a necessity or too many games will end this way. Using a spell like this to force an end of gameplay when such an imbalance occurs will be deemed unfair by at least some of the sociopaths... I mean players... on the other team. But I think it will affect gameplay. People will attack mages first due to the spell's threat.

Answer (score 2):

**Sometimes**

If you are talking about a dozen adventurers battling another dozen equally-skilled and equipped adventurers to the death in a featureless arena, then the spell keeps things fair. Kill Other Team  works like an auto-resolve feature from war video games. By the time five people go down, it usually turns out the other team will win sooner or later. The spell skips to the end.

If you are talking about two countries at war, then the spell does not keep things fair. It amplifies any slight advantage one country has over another.  One country might have a hundred times more wealth and ten times more soldiers and tanks and guns and bombs and fighter planes. But it makes little difference because all it takes to wipe out the other country is a single clever ambush or bomb.

The first assault of the war comes out of nowhere and is also the last assault. Then cast Kill Other Team and zip zap zoop all their soldiers fall down dead.